# error: invalid conversion on const return type

Tags: c++, c, c++11, g++

Using g++ version 4.8.4 I get an error:

error: invalid conversion from ‘const SSL_METHOD* (*)() {aka const ssl_method_st* (*)()}’ to ‘MethodFuncPtr {aka ssl_method_st* (*)()}’ [-fpermissive]

I can compile with -fpermissive, but what is a fix?  I've seen solutions for this type of error, but none for when the return type is const (even though it's explicitly a const return value).

A snippet from ssl.h (C header):

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  typedef struct ssl_method_st {
    int version;
    int (*ssl_new) (int *s);
    void (*ssl_clear) (int *s);
  } SSL_METHOD;

  const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_method(void);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

C++ header:

```
#include <ssl.h>

extern "C" {
  typedef SSL_METHOD*(*MethodFuncPtr)(void);
}

class Method
{
 public:
  Method(SSL_METHOD *method);

  static const MethodFuncPtr TLSv1;

 private:
  SSL_METHOD *m_method;
};
```

C++ source:

```
Method::Method(SSL_METHOD* method)
  : m_method(method)
{ }

const MethodFuncPtr Method::TLSv1 = TLSv1_method;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `Method(SSL_METHOD *method);` be `Method(SSL_METHOD  method);`? Looks you have a pointer to a function pointer, which I suspect you don't want.

Comment: You have a function that returns `const SSL_METHOD *`, and a variable that expects a function returning non-const `SSL_METHOD *`. The two are incompatible. Fix one of them to match the other.

Comment: Not really a C question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a typedef for a const SSL_METHOD* return type.  The compiler is happy.

C++ header:

```
extern "C" {
  typedef SSL_METHOD*(*MethodFuncPtr)(void);
  typedef const SSL_METHOD*(*ConstMethodFuncPtr)(void);
}

class Method
{
 public:
  Method(SSL_METHOD *method);

  static ConstMethodFuncPtr TLSv1;

 private:
  SSL_METHOD *m_method;
};
```

C++ source:

```
Method::Method(SSL_METHOD* method)
  : m_method(method)
{ }

ConstMethodFuncPtr Method::TLSv1 = TLSv1_method;
```